# Fullwidth solutionorgrid with exam-class

Tags: indentation, exam, grid-typesetting, textwidth

The exam-class provides a convenient environment for typesetting either a specified kind of space for students to solve the question or the solution to that question, based on given class options. My problem is, that using the `solutionorgrid` is always indented with the question, so there is a lot of space wasted.

I looked at the definition of `solutionorgrid` and `\fillwithgrid[<length>]`, which `solutionorgrid` seems to be using, but i couldn't figure out how the width of the typset environment is determined.

There is a `\fullwidth{}` command, but it doesn't work for `solutionorgrid` or even only `\fillwithgrid[<length>]`.

Also [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80095/fillwithlines-stretch1-only-6-textwidth) [are](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89251/how-to-break-long-solutions-in-exam-class) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470827/grid-width-not-textwidth-when-using-fillwithgrid-exam-package) [around](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361864/set-grid-width-when-using-fillwithgrid-exam-package) here, that answer similar issues, but none of them really solves my problem.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{exam}
% \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, answers]{exam}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question
  Why ist there air?

  % \fullwidth{ % <== works as expected
  %   \begin{solution}
  %     Because we couldn't breath without air.
  %   \end{solution}
  % }

  % \fullwidth{\fillwithgrid[\stretch{1}]} % <== throws error

  \fullwidth{ % <== works for solutions but doesn't print grid
  \begin{solutionorgrid}[\stretch{1}]
    Because we couldn't breath without air.
  \end{solutionorgrid}
  }

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, the only workaround so far is to use an actual length instead of the `stretch`, for examle `\begin{solutionorgrid}[5cm]`.